# Attaching JS/CSS to forms in Drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-theming

I'm familiar with the process of attaching JavaScript and CSS to specific forms and form items in Drupal 7 using the #attached attribute.

I'm running into an issue which that solves, but unfortunately I'm on a D6 installation.

Basically, drupal_get_form() is being called from the theme layer (in a custom template file).  The form it's printing has form_alter hooks which execute drupal_add_js() (and css), but because the drupal_get_form is being called in the theme layer, those JS files are being added too late, and therefore not being included.

What's the best Drupal 6 solution to this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason why you are calling `drupal_get_form()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the question, `drupal_get_form()` is called too late in the page building process for the `drupal_add_js()` and `drupal_add_js()` calls to have any effect. Calling `drupal_get_form()` in the theme layer is usually not an issue, but in this case I'm assuming that in this case it's called in a `page-<something>.tpl.php`. Becasue of CSS and JS addition happen after the execution of [`template_preprocess_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/6) which build the `$script`, `css`and `$styles` variables.

A simple solution is to call `drupal_get_form()` from your theme's page template preprocessor and then re-build the `$script`, `css` and `$styles` variables.

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $form = drupal_get_form('the_form_name');
  $variables['my_form'] = $form;
  $variables['styles']            = drupal_get_css();
  $variables['css']               = drupal_add_css();
  $variables['scripts']           = drupal_get_js();
}
```

A better solution would be to call `drupal_get_form()` earlier, from a lower level template (such as `node.tpl.php` ou `user.tpl.php`). But the best would be to retrieve the form outside of the theme layer in a page, block, etc. callback function.

Comment: +1 nice, simple way to do this. I've deleted my answer as it no longer seems relevant.